# Visual Studio C# 2010 adding/editing new additional forms to a program

Tags: c#, forms

So I am new to actually building GUI and I am creating a project where when you click on one button you open a new form. With this new form I want to be able to add and edit things to it.

In my solution explorer it is only showing the first form that I originally create, not the second one. I went online and used one of those little microsoft blurbs about creating a new form when a button is clicked, and I am a little lost from there.

My program is going to have multiple buttons that you click and they open certain forms. I understand that I have the button_click set to create a new form. I now want to know how to edit these forms that are created.

I tried refreshing my solution explorer and it wouldn't show my newly created design. (I thought that could be one of my possible errors, haha) Could someone please let me know what I should be doing?

Comment: If your solution is only showing a single form then you have not added another form to your solution.  You need to do this first.

Comment: "one of those little microsoft blurbs"?

Comment: Did you not right click your project in the Solution Explorer panel and use the Context Menu Add-> Windows Form ?

Answer (score 9):

First add a new form. Right click on your project (my project is called `Test`) and give it a name (I called it `TestForm`):
[image: Create a form]

Then, add the following code to your button:

```
TestForm MyForm = new TestForm();
MyForm.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was doing this backwards, adding the code without creating the form.

Comment: For me, I had to type the namespace too. I typed `ProjectName.Form2 frm = new ProjectName.Form2();frm .Show();`. It worked.